# is there a priority filter in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to know if there is filter which would filter by certain no of field probably 4,if all 4 does not match then filter by next three fields(if all 3 fields does not match then match by other 2 fields.)

In the end I want docs that matches 4 fields, if all 4 fields does not match then docs matching 3 fields.

By the query I run, I am able to get all the documents whenever there is a field match.

My doc structure is as below

```
{
  colors: [
    'blue'
  ],
  brands: 'nike',
  size: [
    'xl'
  ],
  features: [
    'sports'
  ]
},
{
  colors: [
    'red'
  ],
  brands: 'adidas',
  size: [
    'xxl'
  ],
  features: [
    'sports'
  ]
},
{
  colors: [
    'green'
  ],
  brands: 'adidas',
  size: [
    'xx'
  ],
  features: [
    'sports'
  ]
}
```

So if I run for search term **"blue xl sports"** it should return the first document only which has all the three matches. Now if there is xl sports it should return first and the third document without the second document.

So the documents should be highest matched fields rather than all the fields.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you search for exact terms as you seem to do, a bool query should do the trick:

```
{
    "bool" : {
        "must" : { },
        "should" : [
            { "match" : { "colors" : "blue" } },
            { "match" : { "brands" : "nike" } },
            { "match" : { "size" : "xxl" } },
            { "match" : { "features" : "sports" } },
        ],
        "minimum_should_match" : 1
    }
}
```

The default sorting of elastic search being the score, you'll get the items matching 4 fields first. If you don't have any, you'll get the ones matching only 3 fields, and so on.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think this will rank higher if all 4 fields are matched, and if 3 fields are matched the score would be lower and it would come in the end which i dont want it to be in case all 4 matched

Comment: is there a way to add a cache to this?

Answer (score 0):

From the words you said:

> So if i run for search term "blue xl sports" it should return the
>   first document only which has all the three matches.

I think this is just the normal query with `and` operator. But about the next paragraph you said:

> Now if there is xl sports it should return first and the third
>   document without the second document.

Does this a typo? Because the `size` of third document is `xx`, I don't see why `xl` can find the third document.

If so, I think the normal query string query with `AND` operator might work for you, such as

`{ "query":{"query_string": {"query": "blue xl sports", "default_operator": "AND"}}}`

You can also put all the three condition into the `must` clause of the `bool` query. I think it also do the job.

Comment: If i put and there then all the three words should match, if there are no matches for all three words then i want it to match 2 fields only. if 2 fields are not matching then it should match only one field.           Also there is no typo there size matches the second document as well hence returns second document. Also my question is based on 3 fields match not three words match.

Comment: according to your logic, the query string `xl sports`, why the third doc can be found? It already found the two-fields fit, that is the first document.

Comment: And I don't think there is such a query like this. This kind of query is just combination of several queries.